# How to solve FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path ="" (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Tags: android, flutter, permissions

I am facing this issue. It is working on my tab android version 7 but not working on mobile android version 11.

**Error :  FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/VidMate/download/'Sooraj_Dooba_Hain'*FULL_VIDEO_SONG*|*Arijit_singh_Aditi_Singh_Sharma*|_T-SERIES(256k).mp3' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)**

I also added all permissions

```
**<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>**
```

and also added this line

```
 **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"**
```

Please help me out.

Comment: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" is only relevant if your app targets SDK 30 and below. If your app targets SDK 31 this feature has no use. Also, I might be wrong here but as far as I remember, Android 11 prevents you from accessing any directory that is not "public". Quite sure "VidMate" is not public and that's why you can't access it. You can use "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission but that will prevent your app from being on the Play Store

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked runtime permission before playing video?

```
var permissionsList = ArrayList<String?>()
permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
requestPermissions(permissionsList.toTypedArray(), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Comment: no i am getting song list and want to put my song file to api in form data. But when ever i post it throws error .                                                                                                Future requestForPermission() async {
    await [
      Permission.storage,
    ].request();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestForPermission();
  }

Comment: how to give runtime permission to song

Comment: just give manual permission by going setting/apps/{your app}/enable storage permission and check if code runs successfully or not if yes then you need to give runtime permission. you can easily get it from google or let me know so I can post it here

Comment: i am working on flutter. So please share code snippet. Thanks

Comment: i am working on flutter. So please share code snippet. Thanks

Comment: Oops I was thinking it was native android issue Thanks I will share if I found any